# SwiftUI ScrollView horizontal scroll lag on macOS

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

Faced with a very strange ScrollView behavior on macOS. The content freezes under the mouse during horizontal scrolling. But it is worth taking the mouse away from the window and the content scrolls normally.

This happens when I try to use a vertical scroll inside a horizontal one:

```swift
struct ScrollTestView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                
                VStack {
                    
                    ForEach(0..<20, id: \.self) { row in
                        
                        HStack {
                            
                            ForEach(0..<20, id: \.self) { item in
                                
                                Text("\(item)")
                                    .font(.title)
                                    .padding()
                                    .background {
                                        Color.gray
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Yes, I know that I can use the same ScrollView for both axes simultaneously, but I need solution with two ScrollViews because of desired UX.

This solution is perfectly works on iOS, but I have this strange behavior on macOS.

Also if you swap a horizontal and a vertical ScrollView in the exact same code, everything works just fine:

```swift
struct ScrollTestView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                
               // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Looks like this is a SwiftUI bug, but I am not sure, maybe I am missing something?

Any ideas?